# php mongodb : Call to undefined method MongoDB::insert() in db.php

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm running this code:

```
    $db = new Mongo("mongodb://user:pw@flame.mongohq.com:27081/dbname");
    $collection = $db->foobar;

    $collection->insert($content);
```

I'm trying to test mongohq by just creating a random collection.

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MongoDB::insert() in /ajax/db.php on line 24
```

I have the client installed as far as I know:

[image]

I'm also running php 5.2.6

What's the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each DB contains one or many collections. You are trying to insert into the DB, instead of the collection.

I've not used that extension, but that method doesn't exist in the `MongoDB` class according to the documentation. Instead, it is `MongoCollection::insert`. You get at a collection by:

```
// $collection = $mongo->selectDB("foo")->selectCollection("bar");
$collection = $mongo->foo->bar; 
$collection->insert(array('x' => 1));
```

(The commented line is equivalent to the line below it.)

I'm guessing that you are doing something like:

```
$collection = $mongo->foo;
$collection->insert(array('x' => 1));
```

(Edit: I didn't see your code snippet the first time. That is precisely what you are doing.)

I suggest that you read the [tutorial](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) for more information.

Comment: Isn't dbname at the end of the new Mongo the db? So I wouldn't have to select it twice?

Comment: You don't insert into a db. You insert into a collection. The `$mongo` instance is just a connection to a mongo server. The first property is the name of the database. The second is the name of the collection.